# How to decode this response From server? I am stuck on it,The "data" in response is in Maps

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My json response from server

```
{"success":1,"error":[],"data":{"38":{"address_id":"38","firstname":"Raj","lastname":"s","company":"","address_1":"aaaa","address_2":"","postcode":"966666","city":"aa","zone_id":"1234","zone":"Kerewan","zone_code":"KE","country_id":"0","country":"","iso_code_2":"","iso_code_3":"","address_format":"","custom_field":null},"37":{"address_id":"37","firstname":"Raj","lastname":"s","company":"","address_1":"4 kk\t","address_2":"","postcode":"56774\t","city":"Chennai\t","zone_id":"1234","zone":"Kerewan","zone_code":"KE","country_id":"0","country":"","iso_code_2":"","iso_code_3":"","address_format":"","custom_field":null},}}
```

My minimal Code

```dart
List<Address> listAddress;

     Future<List<Address>> getAddresList()async {
     List<Address> listAddress;
        {
       try {
      var response = await http.post(
          "URL",
          headers: {"content-type": "application/json", "cookie": cookie});
      List<Address> list = [];
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     var data=convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        for (var item in convert.jsonDecode(response.body)) {
          list.add(AddressOpencart.fromJson(item) as Address);
          }
         }
       setState(() {
        listAddress = list;
        print("DDll"+listAddress.toString());
      });
    } catch (err,trace) {
      print(trace.toString());
      print(err.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

MY Address Model

```dart
Address.fromOpencartJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    try {
      firstName = json['firstname'];
      lastName = json['lastname'];
      street = json['address_1'];
      city = json['city'];
      state = json['zone'];
      country = json['country'];
      phoneNumber = json['phone'];
      zipCode = json['postcode'];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I recommend you to fix your data parameter in response. It should be an array of objects.

Comment: Ok Thanks @AdityaHarshey,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use convert `map` to `list` with `payload.data.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));` and remove control character `\t` and display with `FutureBuilder`

code snippet

```
var response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
  List<Address> list = [];
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String jsonStringNoCtrlChar = response.body.replaceAll("\t", "");
    var payload = payloadFromJson(jsonStringNoCtrlChar);
    payload.data.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));
    return list;
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  int success;
  List<dynamic> error;
  Map<String, Address> data;

  Payload({
    this.success,
    this.error,
    this.data,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        success: json["success"],
        error: List<dynamic>.from(json["error"].map((x) => x)),
        data: Map.from(json["data"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Address>(k, Address.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "error": List<dynamic>.from(error.map((x) => x)),
        "data": Map.from(data)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class Address {
  String addressId;
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String company;
  String address1;
  String address2;
  String postcode;
  String city;
  String zoneId;
  String zone;
  String zoneCode;
  String countryId;
  String country;
  String isoCode2;
  String isoCode3;
  String addressFormat;
  dynamic customField;

  Address({
    this.addressId,
    this.firstname,
    this.lastname,
    this.company,
    this.address1,
    this.address2,
    this.postcode,
    this.city,
    this.zoneId,
    this.zone,
    this.zoneCode,
    this.countryId,
    this.country,
    this.isoCode2,
    this.isoCode3,
    this.addressFormat,
    this.customField,
  });

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
        addressId: json["address_id"],
        firstname: json["firstname"],
        lastname: json["lastname"],
        company: json["company"],
        address1: json["address_1"],
        address2: json["address_2"],
        postcode: json["postcode"],
        city: json["city"],
        zoneId: json["zone_id"],
        zone: json["zone"],
        zoneCode: json["zone_code"],
        countryId: json["country_id"],
        country: json["country"],
        isoCode2: json["iso_code_2"],
        isoCode3: json["iso_code_3"],
        addressFormat: json["address_format"],
        customField: json["custom_field"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "address_id": addressId,
        "firstname": firstname,
        "lastname": lastname,
        "company": company,
        "address_1": address1,
        "address_2": address2,
        "postcode": postcode,
        "city": city,
        "zone_id": zoneId,
        "zone": zone,
        "zone_code": zoneCode,
        "country_id": countryId,
        "country": country,
        "iso_code_2": isoCode2,
        "iso_code_3": isoCode3,
        "address_format": addressFormat,
        "custom_field": customField,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<Address>> _future;

  Future<List<Address>> getAddresList() async {
    try {
      /*var response = await http.post(
            "URL",
            headers: {"content-type": "application/json", "cookie": cookie});*/

      String jsonString = '''
        {"success":1,
"error":[],
"data":
  {"38":
         {"address_id":"38",
          "firstname":"Raj",
          "lastname":"s",
          "company":"",
          "address_1":"aaaa",
          "address_2":"",
          "postcode":"966666",
          "city":"aa",
          "zone_id":"1234",
          "zone":"Kerewan",
          "zone_code":"KE",
          "country_id":"0",
          "country":"",
          "iso_code_2":"",
          "iso_code_3":"",
          "address_format":"",
          "custom_field":null},
    "37":{"address_id":"37","firstname":"Raj","lastname":"s","company":"","address_1":"4 kk\t","address_2":"","postcode":"56774\t","city":"Chennai\t","zone_id":"1234","zone":"Kerewan","zone_code":"KE","country_id":"0","country":"","iso_code_2":"","iso_code_3":"","address_format":"","custom_field":null}}

}
        ''';
      var response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
      List<Address> list = [];
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String jsonStringNoCtrlChar = response.body.replaceAll("\t", "");
        var payload = payloadFromJson(jsonStringNoCtrlChar);
        payload.data.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));
        return list;
      }
    } catch (err, trace) {
      print(trace.toString());
      print(err.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getAddresList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Address>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].addressId),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].address1),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very much,For Taking your time to help me @chunhunghan,Overwhelmed!!!

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must fix your data parameter in API response. It should be an array of objects.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "error": [

  ],
  "data": [
     {
      "address_id": "38",
      "firstname": "Raj",
      "lastname": "s",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "aaaa",
      "address_2": "",
      "postcode": "966666",
      "city": "aa",
      "zone_id": "1234",
      "zone": "Kerewan",
      "zone_code": "KE",
      "country_id": "0",
      "country": "",
      "iso_code_2": "",
      "iso_code_3": "",
      "address_format": "",
      "custom_field": null
    },
    {
      "address_id": "37",
      "firstname": "Raj",
      "lastname": "s",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "4 kk\t",
      "address_2": "",
      "postcode": "56774\t",
      "city": "Chennai\t",
      "zone_id": "1234",
      "zone": "Kerewan",
      "zone_code": "KE",
      "country_id": "0",
      "country": "",
      "iso_code_2": "",
      "iso_code_3": "",
      "address_format": "",
      "custom_field": null
    }

  ]
}
```

Now, your code looks good to me but with few changes in it:

```
 Future<List<Address>> getAddresList()async {
   List<Address> listAddress;

   try {
        var response = await http.post(
            "URL",
            headers: {"content-type": "application/json", "cookie": cookie});
        List<Address> list = List<Address>();
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
            for (var item in data["data"]) {
                list.add(AddressOpencart.fromJson(item) as Address);
            }
        }
        setState(() {
            listAddress = list;
            print("DDll"+listAddress.toString());
        });
  } catch (err,trace) {
    print(trace.toString());
    print(err.toString());    
  }
}

Address.fromOpencartJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
  firstName = json['firstname'],
  lastName = json['lastname'],
  street = json['address_1'],
  city = json['city'],
  state = json['zone'],
  country = json['country'],
  phoneNumber = json['phone'],
  zipCode = json['postcode'];
```